# Unrecognized attribute 'fcnMode'. Note that attribute names are case-sensitive

Tags: asp.net, web-config, dotnetnuke, .net-framework-version, dotnetnuke-7

I am getting this error on my PROD server but on my DEV server no such error occurs.

My DNN website has `fcnMode="Single"` in the `web.config` file on both PROD and DEV servers.

Also .NET framework on both the servers is 4.0.

This [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.fcnmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) says `fcnMode="Single"` is supported since 4.5. Then how it is working on my DEV server or am I missing something on PROD server?

Following is my `web.config` section

```
<httpRuntime useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="true" 
maxRequestLength="8192" requestLengthDiskThreshold="8192" 
maxQueryStringLength="2048" requestValidationMode="2.0" 
fcnMode="Single" requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,*,%,:,\,?" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Just because IIS app pool is .net v4 doesn't mean you may have version 4.5 of .net installed on your dev machine and not your production server.

Here are instructions for looking up the latest .NET version installed on your machine.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh925568(v=vs.110).aspx